# problems creating a keytab file on win server

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, kerberos, single-sign-on, gssapi

I am trying to create a keytab file. i see a warning

```
  WARNING: pType and account type do not match. This might cause  problems.
```

The command i use is

```
  ktpass -princ HTTP/bloodhound.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM -mapuser ldaplookup@domain.com -crypto rc4-hmac-nt -pass **** -ptype KRB5_NT_SRV_HST -out "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\bloodhound.kytab"
```

I want to use this for SSO on apache. I am creating this on windows server 2003 r2 sp2

output

```
Targeting domain controller: fezziwig.uk.domain.com
Using legacy password setting method
Successfully mapped HTTP/bloodhound.domain.com to ldaplookup.
WARNING: pType and account type do not match. This might cause  problems.
Key created.
Output keytab to C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.UK-GGS-DOMAIN\bloodhound.keytab:
Keytab version: 0x502
keysize 82 HTTP/bloodhound.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM ptype 3 (KRB5_NT_SRV_HST) vno 14 etype 0x17 (RC4-HMAC) keylength 16 (0xde184005d851613980cffb9580bdd193)
```

I have followed many steps that show same as http://www.zimbra.com/docs/os/7.2.3/administration_guide/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=7.2.3_Open_Source_admin.Create_the_Kerberos_Keytab_File.html&single=true

But none do not work. when i test with kvno i get following

```
[root@portal-test conf]# klist -ke bloodhound1.keytab 
Keytab name: FILE:bloodhound1.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  27 HTTP/bloodhound.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM (ArcFour with HMAC/md5) 
[root@portal-test conf]# kvno HTTP/bloodhound.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
kvno: Server not found in Kerberos database while getting credentials for HTTP/bloodhound.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM
```

**Update**

webserver i want to access using url http://cobra.woking/

following command i enetered in windows server 2008 r2 standard

```
ktpass -princ HTTP/cobra.woking@spectrumasa.com -mapuser ldaplookup@spectrumasa.com -crypto rc4-hmac-nt -pass password -ptype KRB5_NT_SRV_HST -out "C:\Temp\cobra.kytab" -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL

Targeting domain controller: echo.spectrumasa.com
Successfully mapped HTTP/cobra.woking to ldaplookup.
Password succesfully set!
Key created.
Output keytab to C:\Temp\cobra.kytab:
Keytab version: 0x502
keysize 68 HTTP/cobra.woking@spectrumasa.com ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 33 etype 0x17 (RC4-HMAC
) keylength 16 (0xde184005d851613980cffb9580bdd193)
```

copied file over to webserver. updated webserver config to:

```
<Directory /opt/html/trac>
        AuthType Kerberos
        AuthName KerberosLogin
        KrbServiceName HTTP/cobra.woking
        KrbMethodNegotiate On
        KrbMethodK5Passwd On
        KrbAuthRealms SPECTRUMASA.COM
        Krb5KeyTab /tmp/cobra.kytab

        AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldapauth.spectrumasa.com/ou=TechSupport,ou=Woking,ou=Sites,dc=spectrumasa,dc=com?userPrincipalName
        AuthLDAPBindDN cn=ldaplookup,cn=Users,dc=spectrumasa,dc=com
        AuthLDAPBindPassword password

        #require valid-user
        Require ldap-group cn=support,cn=Users,dc=spectrumasa,dc=com
        ErrorDocument 401 "<html><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=/intranet/info/unauthorized\"></html>"
</Directory>
```

tested keytab

```
klist -ke cobra.kytab 
Keytab name: FILE:cobra.kytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  33 HTTP/cobra.woking@spectrumasa.com (arcfour-hmac) 

kvno HTTP/cobra.woking@spectrumasa.com
kvno: Ticket expired while getting credentials for HTTP/cobra.woking@spectrumasa.com
```

When accessing the url i get in ie, but in firefox i get password prompt then it works.

```
gss_accept_sec_context() failed: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (, ), referer: http://cobra.woking/trac/
```

How do i fix this?

I already have an `intranet` keytab file working for this server

```
[root@cobra conf]# klist -ke intranet.keytab
Keytab name: FILE:intranet.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   8 HTTP/intranet.spectrumasa.com@SPECTRUMASA.COM (arcfour-hmac) 
[root@cobra conf]# kvno HTTP/intranet.spectrumasa.com@SPECTRUMASA.COM
kvno: Ticket expired while getting credentials for HTTP/intranet.spectrumasa.com@SPECTRUMASA.COM
```

**2nd update**

I have recreated keytab again using following

```
ktpass -princ HTTP/cobra@SPECTRUMASA.COM -mapuser ldaplookup@spectrumasa.com -crypto rc4-hmac-nt -pass password -out "C:\Temp\cobra1.keytab" -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL
```

in my DNS i have

```
  cobra         A   172.16.0.216
```

in apache i have

```
KrbServiceName HTTP/cobra
Krb5KeyTab /etc/httpd/conf/cobra1.keytab
```

When i try to access `http::/cobra/trac` i get asked for my password 3 times. the log shows

on url enter. 1st password prompt display `SPECTRUM/user`

```
gss_accept_sec_context() failed: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (, )
```

2nd password prompt display `COBRA/user` and log shows

```
gss_accept_sec_context() failed: No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible (, Unknown error)
```

3rd password prompt i have to enter user and password and it works.

I have added `http://cobra` and `http://cobra.spectrumasa.com` to ie trusted sites.

Comment: Given how old and close to EoS Server 2003 is, you really ought to replace it.  The fact that something isn't working on 2003 is a perfect pretense to update it to something modern.  As a bonus, you have a better chance of finding someone who can actually help you with your issue.

Comment: i have server 2008 in the domain as well

Answer (score 5):

The error you get in the output is because you are not mapping the SPN to a principal.
You should use a ptype switch of `-ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL` so as to avoid the error.

KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL is the general principal type (recommended) as [documented by Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753771.aspx).

Comment: i have updated question.